# P(A) - P(B), do I have to remove the ∅ from the resulting set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If I have a set $A = \{1, 3\}$ and a set $B = \{2, 4\}$ where $P(A) = \{∅, \{1\}, \{3\}, \{1, 3\}\}$ and $P(A) = \{∅, \{2\}, \{4\}, \{2, 4\}\}$

if I do $P(A) - P(B)$, do I get a set like $\{\{1\}, \{3\}, \{1, 3\}\}$?

[This is the original problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv38y.png), it is the 5.b.
I'm doing practice because I have a test

Comment: Basically your question is "is the empty set which is a subset of $A$ the same empty set which is a subset of $B$?" I'm inclined to say the answer is "yes" assuming that both $A$ and $B$ are understood as subsets of the same outer universe (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: In the original problem, it doesn't say if they are on the same universe, now that I read it again

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Ratsiev Here it makes sense to think of them as being in the same universe, be it $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{N}$ or whatever. Sorry if my remark confused you, your class almost certainly intends for you to think of every $\emptyset$ as the same (as is the case in pure set theory, at the very least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. The empty set that is an element of $\mathcal P(A)$ is the same as the empty set that is the element of $\mathcal P(B)$, so removing all elements of $\mathcal P(B)$ eliminates it from $\mathcal P(A)$ and leaves the rest because there are no other elements shared.